# .NET Core Web API validate token received from multiple issuers

Tags: azure, .net-core, jwt, openid-connect, okta

I want to enable my API to start accepting tokens issued by any identity provider (like other Azure AD, Okta - I'll keep client ID and authority in my settings), one request comes for Azure another will come for Okta, so by looking at the token, I should be able to validate it and send response.

Any right approach or technical correction you can suggest?

[in progress code file- start.cs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_76-bhFhj5LjMNOvmMVpn0-Q9hv9dkGV/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The general approach that I would take would be to make one of them the default scheme and define a `ForwardDefaultSelector` on that which checks the incoming token's issuer and changes the default scheme for that request accordingly if needed.

Comment: Checking issuer, audience, token expiry and request is coming from known domain, I can do that, but how should I be assured the token issued is valid? anyone can create JWT token with any issuer and audience, so I should be able to it

Comment: Well the actual token validation would be done by the authentication scheme for that service (e.g. Okta token authentication). That would do the signature validation etc. so you know it was created by that service and not modified by someone. The purpose of the selector would be just to select which scheme to use to do the validation.